# como mostrar e esconder uma div

Tags: javascript

boas tenho este codigo que supostamente devia dar para mostrar e esconder uma div mas não me esta funcionado. `

```
    <div  class="btn-group custom-btn-group"   data-toggle="buttons">
                    <label class="btn btn-default active" >
                        <img src="img/3d-pie-chart-icon.png" alt="" />
                        <input id="circular" type="radio" class="form-control" name="circular"  value="0"   checked="checked"  />

                    </label>
                    <label class="btn btn-default"  >
                        <img src="img/SEO-icon.png" alt=""   />
                        <input  id="barras" type="radio" class="form-control"  name="barras" value="1"    />
                    </label>
                </div>$("#barrasgrafico").on("change", function () {
                   $("#bar_div").show();
                   $("#chart_div").hide();
               });
               $("#circulargrafico").on("change", function () {
                   $("#bar_div").hide();
                   $("#chart_div").show();
               });`
```

Comment: Onde estão as `divs` correspondentes aos **ID's** `bar_div` e `chart_div` ?

Comment: Seu código javascript está fora da tag `<script></script>`?

Comment: as div estão a seguir a primeira div sim o codigo ta dentro do javascript

Answer (score 4):

Você tem vários problemas no seu código se é esse mesmo seu código completo,
pra começar você  não esta separando o seu javascript do html, você deve utilizar um `<script></script>`
é já que você utiliza código jquery deve incluir a biblioteca antes.
se ja foi feito, veja que você esta querendo esconder/mostrar objetos que não existem, por exemplo: não existe o `circulargrafico`.

Vou deixar um exemplo desse processo funcionando:

```js
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
  $("#div1,#div2").hide(); // seletores que serão escondidos
  var div = $(this).val(); // pega o valor do input radio que é o nome da div a ser mostrada.
  $('#' + div).show(); // mostra a div 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="div1" checked>Mostra div 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" value="div2">Mostra div 2</label>
</div>
<div id="div1">Conteúdo da Div 1</div>
<div id="div2">Conteúdo da Div 2</div>
```